# AsyncTask works sporadically Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I have a MapsActivity to show Google Maps on my app. 
I have a text file where I have street names, zip codes and city names. I read this text file using BufferedReader. There are nearly 100 streets in my text file. So, I programmatically add nearly 100 markers in Google Map. That takes time, and it depends on the internet connection.

Therefore I decided to use AsyncTask. Since I know, that UI things cannot be done in `doInBackground` I put my `readfile()` method (which adds these 100 markers) in `doInBackground` as a runnable Thread. And I don't want the user to see a blank screen, therefore I added a ProgressBar.

**And here is the problem:** The Progressbar does not work always, it is not always to seen, it is sporadically to seen, which leds me to the assumption that something is wrong with my Asycntask. Maybe the way I call my AsyncTask is bad. Please have a look at my code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;
String city, adress, zip;
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    new Test().execute(null,null,null); //calling AsyncTask

}


public void readFile() {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p2;

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("liste.txt")));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String splittedLine[] = line.split(",");
            int numberofElements = 2;
            String[] onlyAdressandZip = Arrays.copyOf(splittedLine, numberofElements);

            if ( address.size() !=0) {

                Address location = address.get(0);
                location.getLatitude();
                location.getLongitude();

                p2 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(p2).title("Location " + onlyAdressandZip[0]+"," + onlyAdressandZip[1]));
                builder.include(p2);

                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20));

            }

              }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // what to do before background task
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                readFile();

            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void foo) {
    super.onPostExecute(foo);
    dialog.cancel();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: you are trying to execute a uithread on a workers thread. you should read the file in background and use `onProgressUpdate()` (it runs in the uithread by calling `publishProgress()`) to update the progressbar. Read some more about [AsyncTask in here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)..

Comment: @MatiasOlocco can you show me a code example please?

Comment: In the documentation there is a perfectly working example, please read it.

Comment: Also, since you expect Void, you could call, `new Test().execute()`, without all the nulls.

Comment: Obviously all this does not answer your question, it is just how you should build that asynctask before worrying about why the progress bar is not visibile.

Comment: @MatiasOlocco What is wrong with building the asynctask ?
And btw: the progress bar is visible, but not always.

Comment: the whole point of having an async task is to run things in a worker thread... you are running an uithread in the worker thread... dont you see what is wrong in there? basically the Asynctask is useless how you implemented it.

Comment: @MatiasOlocco therefore I added a runnable thread. I know that UI things cannot be done in worker thread. But I read, when using a runnable Thread you can do UI Things in worker thread.

Comment: Yes, but you are doing EVERYTHING in there, so, why do you have the asynctask at all???

Comment: Im preparing an example for you..., but without the full code, you should do that yourself.

Comment: @MatiasOlocco I have a asynctask because I dont want the user to see a blank screen, while I am loading hundreds of markers into google Map. I want to show a progressdialog at the same time while adding markers. I hope, you understand my problem

Comment: I understand the problem, you are not getting it... please check the example, hopefully is better.

Comment: @MatiasOlocco Ok, I will wait, thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151876/discussion-between-matias-olocco-and-ckbln).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I said in the comments, in this example, basically I re-wrote your async task to run the reading of the file in the background, and updating the progress of the map in the uithread. The code is far from final, but you should test and improve it.

Because an AsyncTask gives you the tools to update uithreads, you should never use `runOnUiThread()` in there.

The [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) says:

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows you to perform background operations and publish results on the
>   UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.

**The example:**

```
public class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, WrapperObject, Void> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // what to do before background task
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait.");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> address;
        LatLng p2;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("liste.txt")));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String splittedLine[] = line.split(",");
                int numberofElements = 2;
                String[] onlyAdressandZip = Arrays.copyOf(splittedLine, numberofElements);

                if (address.size() != 0) {

                    Address location = address.get(0);
                    location.getLatitude();
                    location.getLongitude();

                    p2 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    builder.include(p2);

                    WrapperObject wrapperObject = new WrapperObject();
                    wrapperObject.bounds = builder.build();
                    wrapperObject.latlng = p2;
                    wrapperObject.onlyAdressandZip = onlyAdressandZip;
                    publishProgress(wrapperObject);
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(WrapperObject... wrapperObjects) {
        WrapperObject wrapperObject = wrapperObjects[0];
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(wrapperObject.latlng).title("Location " + wrapperObject.onlyAdressandZip[0]+"," + wrapperObject.onlyAdressandZip[1]));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(wrapperObject.bounds, 20));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void foo) {
        super.onPostExecute(foo);
        dialog.cancel();
    }
}
//this is a wrapper to update the progress, you should make this better.    
public static class WrapperObject {
    public LatLng latlng;
    public LatLngBounds bounds;
    public String[] onlyAdressandZip;
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Please be sure you read and understand the doc. it is important to know how to use Asynctasks in the future.